# Is it possible to set a custom default TaskFactory?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, task-parallel-library

Related to my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813359/translating-async-await-c-sharp-code-to-f-with-respect-to-the-scheduler), I wonder if it is possible to set a custom default [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to be used AppDomain-wide by [Task.Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The examples I see use it explicitly.

One way I can imagine is to write a [custom workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) in F#, say *customasync*. But [exposing it to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677366/how-to-call-and-handle-an-asynchronous-f-workflow-from-c-sharp) looks like being clumsy.

Comment: Just create a new instance of `TaskBuilder` (FSharpx) and pass in `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Comment: No, that would be bad design because you don't know what code is running in the AppDomain besides your code. Libraries and the BCL might rely on a specific Task.Factory behavior. This is a global solution to a local problem.

Comment: @Daniel, as you kindly showed. I considered this, but I wondered why Orleans has such a restriction as to not to use many of the functions as they go to thread pool pass the custom scheduler and would an "easy fix" be to just force a custom TaskFactory. Perhaps it would have been created bugs, but thinking if there's a way to do it nevertheless was interesting. I suppose there's always a way, but this time not an easy on (to do this particular thing).

Usr, Perhaps so, but I phrased my question poorly. See comment pointed at Daniel.